# Assembly Description Max Size

Tags: .net-assembly

Does anyone know if the assembly description property in the AssemblyInfo.cs below has a maximum size? And if so, what is it?

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Template")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("A simple template")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Sample Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Template")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("")]
```

Comment: Your main (and only) tag was misleading, because it had nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this too.  Can't seem to find it in the win32 format docs.  This should be a property of the underlying format and not specific to .net, because win32 c/c++ binaries can have a file descriptions too.

My guess is this is a pointer to the statics section, so treated like a string literal, and the maximum size for that compiling with Microsoft visual studio tool chain would be roughly [sic] 65536 from http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/maximum-string-length?view=vs-2019

To confirm, I ran different sized strings through the vs2015 compiler tool chain until it threw a CS7065, "Error building Win32 resources -- Arthmetic operation resulted in an overflow."  The maximum value seems to be around 32755 characters.  This count is multipled by 2 because of wide encoding, and pretty close to the 65536.

Not sure why microsoft says "roughly".

It is worth pointing out certain special characters like \r\n cannot be printed/recovered, so don't try to write a book.